# Java - printing a 2D array for Conways Game of Life

Tags: java

I started today to program Conways Game of Life. In a first step, I just want the user to input the length of the (squadratic) field which is then displayed on the screen. But I'm getting a NullPointerException in the printGrid() method. Here are the necessary code examples:

```
public class Grid {
private Cell[][]grid;

public Grid (int feldlänge) {
    grid = new Cell[feldlänge][feldlänge];
    int x, y;
    for (y = 0; y < feldlänge; y = y + 1) {
        for (x = 0; x < feldlänge; x = x + 1) {
            Cell cell;
            cell = new Cell(x,y);
            cell.setLife(false); 
        } // for     
    } // for
} // Konstruktor Grid    

public String printGrid () {
    String ausgabe = "";
    int x, y;
    for (y = 0; y < grid.length; y = y + 1) {
        for (x = 0; x  < grid.length; x = x + 1) {
            if (grid[x][y].isAlive()) {   // Here's the NullPointerException
                ausgabe = ausgabe + "■";
            }
            if (!grid[x][y].isAlive()) {
                ausgabe = ausgabe + "□";
            }
        }
        ausgabe = ausgabe + "\n";
    }

    return ausgabe;
}


public class Cell {
private int x, y;
private boolean isAlive;

public Cell (int pX, int pY) {
    x = pX;
    y = pY;
} // Konstruktor Cell

public void setLife (boolean pLife) {
    isAlive = pLife;
} // Methode setLife

public int getX () {
    return x;
} // Methode getX

public int getY () {
    return y;
} // Methode getY  

public boolean isAlive () {
    return isAlive;
}
}
```

It's kind of embarrassing I can't find the mistake by myself. I guess I'm overlooking something simple.
Already thanks a lot for any help!

**Update: Already solved!**
I just didn't add the cell to the array. It works now.

Comment: You never add your `Cell`s to the array.

Comment: Oh god, thanks a lot! I knew it was something stupid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to add the cell into your grid array.

```
public Grid (int feldlänge) {
    grid = new Cell[feldlänge][feldlänge];
    int x, y;
    for (y = 0; y < feldlänge; y = y + 1) {
        for (x = 0; x < feldlänge; x = x + 1) {
            Cell cell;
            cell = new Cell(x,y);
            cell.setLife(false); 
            grid[x][y] = cell; //put the cell in the grid.
        } // for     
    } // for
} // Konstruktor Grid
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add cell to your array. (german field = english array)

Also: instead of

```
 if( someBoolean){}
 if( !someBoolean){}
```

you should use

```
if( someBoolean){}
else {}
```

This makes it more clear what the code does